# Move rows between two sortable DataGrids that use DataTables as sorces

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I know this seems like a common problem but I've been searching for quite a while now and I can't find anything that solves my problem.

I have two DataTables and two DataGrids (each DataTable is an ItemSource for a DataGrid). When I double click on a row in any of the DataGrids, the row moves to the other DataGrid. Here is my code for one of the MouseDoubleClick events:

```
// Predefined stuff:
DataTable sourceDT;
DataTable targetDT;

// This is called when a DataGridRow in a specific DataGrid is double-clicked
private void WorkerRowSource_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var rowView = sender as DataGridRow;
    var row = sourceDT.Rows[rowView.GetIndex()];

    targetDT.ImportRow(row);
    sourceDT.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

This doesn't work after I sort DataGrid by a column because the line `rowView.GetIndex()` returns the index of rowView in the sorted DataGrid, while I need rowView's index in an unsorted DataGrid (or in the ItemSource).

An answer from a thread I found earlier today said that using `sourceDT.DefaultView.ToTable()` would solve this problem, but if I use this I need to replace my DataTables and the DataGrids' ItemSources (doing this also cancels the sorting of the DataGrid).

Am I missing something? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out but I don't like this solution. My MouseDoubleClick events now look like this:

```
// Predefined stuff:
DataTable sourceDT;
DataTable targetDT;

DataGrid sourceDAGRI;

private void WorkerRowSource_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var rowView = sender as DataGridRow;
    var cellContent = sourceDAGRI.Columns[1].GetCellContent(rowView);
    int num = int.Parse((cellContent as TextBlock).Text);

    DataRow row = null;
    foreach (DataRow dRow in sourceDT.Rows)
        if ((int)dRow[_numKey] == num)
        {
            row = dRow;
            break;
        }

    targetDT.ImportRow(row);
    sourceDT.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

This gets the value of the cells in the DataGridRow and attempts to find a row that has the same Values in the DataTable (so that I dont rely on DataGridRow.GetIndex()).

Comment: Finding a row with "the same values" seems like a smell.  Why does your row not have a proper unique row value?

Comment: One of the values that is being saved is unique so I only search for that value. I didn't type this in my answer because I Thought it was irrelevant.

Comment: If you set selection mode to single item then clicking a row selects it. You can then bind selecteditem and that will give you a reference to a datagridrowview or some such that you can work with. A datatable ought to be your choice of last resort to hold data and then only when your data is so dynamic that defining a viewmodel is not practical.